# javascript countdown timer user input

Tags: javascript

Trying to build a simple countdown timer with user input.

I'm trying to simply count down the seconds with a reverse for loop and it doesn't seem to be working for me.
can I get some assistance please and thank you.

```
//button
let button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.addEventListener('click', timer);

//Seconds variable
let seconds = 60;

function timer(){
    let mins = parseInt(document.getElementById('min').value);

    //Make the seconds tick down from 60
    for(let i= seconds - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        setInterval(function(){
            seconds[i]}, 1000);
        console.log(seconds[i]);
    }
    if(mins === 0 && seconds == 0){
        console.log('completed')

    }else{
        console.log('still going');
    }

    //output the time.
    let time= document.getElementById('time');
    
};
```

Comment: You should make your function into `setInterval`, or it's just called once when click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure why you'd want a `seconds` variable and also a `mins` variable, but here's the code. You don't need a for loop here.

The reason for not needing a for loop is, the `setInterval(function (){}, time_in_sec);` method takes two arguments.

1. The function to be called after waiting for a time of `time_in_sec` seconds. This function is repeatedly called untill we do `clearInterval()`.
2. The number of seconds to wait (`time_in_sec`) before calling that function again.

So the `setInterval()` method itself is iterative, and hence no need a for loop.

```js
var myCounter;

//button
let button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.addEventListener('click', timer);

//Seconds variable
let seconds = 60;

function timer() {
  clearInterval(myCounter); //to stop counter if already counting.
  let mins = parseInt(document.getElementById('min').value);
  var i = mins * seconds;
  myCounter = setInterval(function() {
    if (i < 0) {
      console.log('completed');
      clearInterval(myCounter);

    } else {
      console.log(i--);
      console.log('still going');
      let time = document.getElementById('time');
      time.innerHTML = i;
    }

  }, 1000);
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="min">
  <button id="btn">Click me</button>
  <p id="time">
    Time
  </p>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code here. Your for loop will create 60 different setIntervals. I recommend you research how asynchronous JavaScript works a bit more. Try something more like this for your timer function:

```
let i  = 60;

const intervalFunction = () => {
    console.log(i);
    if (i < 1) {
        clearInterval(interval)
    }
    i--;
}

let interval = setInterval( intervalFunction, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tstart,si,elaps;
var c = document.getElementById("c");

function cd(){

  var dc = new Date();  
  var tnow = dc.getTime()/1000;
  var tdiff = tnow - tstart;
  c.innerHTML = elaps - tdiff;
  console.log(c.innerHTML);
  if (tdiff >= parseFloat(elaps)){  
      clearInterval(si);
  }
}
function docd(){  
  clearInterval(si);
  elaps = document.getElementById("cd").value;
  var ds = new Date();  
  tstart = ds.getTime()/1000;
  si = setInterval(cd,100);
}
```

```html
<h3>countdown timer user input</h3>
<input type="text"   id="cd" value="15">
<input type="button" onclick="docd()" value="start/restart">
<div id="c"></div>
```